# Restore PYTHONPATH after setup.py install with PYTHONPATH

Tags: linux, python

I ran this command on Ubuntu 14.04 Linux while trying to install a package:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ && sudo python setup.py install
```

The package I was trying to install is http://github.com/ewels/MultiQC

Then lots of things python related have gone wrong since this. For example, virtualenv doesn't work anymore, and this package doesn't work either:

http://wiki.dnanexus.com/images/files/dx-toolkit-v0.240.1-ubuntu-14.04-amd64.tar.gz

```
source Downloads/dx-toolkit/environment
dx login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/bin/dx", line 7, in <module>
    from dxpy.scripts.dx import main
  File "/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dxpy/__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dxpy/exceptions.py", line 211, in <module>
    network_exceptions = (requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'
```

How do I revert this to the stage before running this command-line? Even starting from a fresh bash terminal, it now won't find any of my other python libraries.
Even with a freshly created Linux user on the same computer, the errors are the same.

Related question wasn't answered: [Fixing a broken PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206862/fixing-a-broken-pythonpath-environment-variable)

**[EDIT]**

I don't know how to revert to the list of folders before, but I presume it was a combination of /usr/lib/python2.7 and /usr/local/lib/python2.7

Trying virtualenv also fails now:

```
virtualenv
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Interactive python works to the extend I tried below:

```
avilella@ubuntu14:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "foo"
foo
>>> import urllib3
>>>
```

I have now gone through the folder and tried both `pip install` and `apt-get install python-${package}` with this:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*/ | grep -v egg | grep '\:' | tr ':' ' ' | grep -v dist-info | xargs -n1 basename  | while read i; do sudo pip install $i; done
```

Also:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*/ | grep -v egg | grep '\:' | tr ':' ' ' | grep -v dist-info | xargs -n1 basename  | while read i; do sudo apt-get install -y python-${i}; done
```

But still same issues.

Package requests is there:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/
total 304
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14594 Mar 26  2015 adapters.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 13750 Sep  4 16:05 adapters.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4333 Sep 24  2013 api.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  5261 Sep  4 16:05 api.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6173 Dec  5  2013 auth.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  7206 Sep  4 16:05 auth.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   527 Mar 26  2015 certs.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   736 Sep  4 16:05 certs.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2531 Mar 26  2015 compat.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2541 Sep  4 16:05 compat.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16686 Jan  8  2014 cookies.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 20167 Sep  4 16:05 cookies.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1599 Mar 26  2015 exceptions.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  3863 Sep  4 16:05 exceptions.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   820 Sep 24  2013 hooks.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1055 Sep  4 16:05 hooks.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1846 Mar 26  2015 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2501 Sep  4 16:05 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25332 Mar 26  2015 models.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 23051 Sep  4 16:05 models.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22042 Mar 26  2015 sessions.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 18049 Sep  4 16:05 sessions.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3136 Sep 24  2013 status_codes.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  4439 Sep  4 16:05 status_codes.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3575 Sep 24  2013 structures.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  6359 Sep  4 16:05 structures.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19642 Mar 26  2015 utils.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 19386 Sep  4 16:05 utils.pyc
```

I checked a working version of a different VM I have, where everything python related works, and the requests folder contains *exactly* the same files.

Any mentions to urllib in the non-working Linux (below) are the same as in the working one (further below), with 2 files changing their date between one an the other:

```
[       4096 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3
[       3346 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/_collections.pyc
[      22000 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.pyc
[       4096 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib
[       6015 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/exceptions.pyc
[       6511 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/fields.pyc
[       3162 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.pyc
[       2074 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.pyc
[       4096 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/packages
[       9076 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.pyc
[       5850 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.pyc
[       9879 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.pyc
[      19662 Sep  4 16:05]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util.pyc
[      28639 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
[       5961 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/fields.py
[       2486 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.py
[      10159 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py
[      20575 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util.py
[       1703 Sep 25  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py
[       3274 Sep 25  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py
[       2898 Aug 14  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/_collections.py
[       9009 Aug 14  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py
[       5874 Aug 14  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py
[      17079 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3-1.7.1.egg-info
[       7142 Oct  5 14:47]  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/fixes/fix_urllib.pyc
[       8385 Oct 26  2016]  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/fixes/fix_urllib.py
[      46549 Oct  5 14:47]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc
[      50626 Oct  5 14:47]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc
[      51788 Oct 26  2016]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
[      59371 Oct 26  2016]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py
```

The working one below:

```
[       4096 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3
[       3346 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/_collections.pyc
[      22000 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.pyc
[       4096 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib
[       6015 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/exceptions.pyc
[       6511 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/fields.pyc
[       3162 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.pyc
[       2074 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.pyc
[       4096 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/packages
[       9076 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.pyc
[       5850 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.pyc
[       9879 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.pyc
[      19662 Jul 10  9:06]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util.pyc
[      28639 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
[       5961 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/fields.py
[       2486 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.py
[      10159 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py
[      20575 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util.py
[       1703 Sep 25  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py
[       3274 Sep 25  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py
[       2898 Aug 14  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/_collections.py
[       9009 Aug 14  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py
[       5874 Aug 14  2013]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py
[      17079 Oct 12  2015]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3-1.7.1.egg-info
[      46549 Jul 12 11:47]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc
[      50626 Jul 12 11:47]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc
[       7142 Jul 12 11:47]  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/fixes/fix_urllib.pyc
[       8385 Oct 26  2016]  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/fixes/fix_urllib.py
[      51788 Oct 26  2016]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
[      59371 Oct 26  2016]  /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py
```

Another example tool that doesn't work anymore is `tosheets` https://github.com/kren1/tosheets:

```
tosheets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tosheets", line 7, in <module>
    from tosheets.tosheets import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tosheets/tosheets.py", line 27, in <module>
    from apiclient import discovery
ImportError: cannot import name discovery
```

After doing `unset PYTHON`, then:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/multiqc-1.4dev-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/lib/python', '/home/avilella', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/avilella/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

unset PYTHON, the python3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/avilella/Downloads/dx-toolkit/lib/python', '/home/avilella', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

The contents of $PYTHONPATH before doing any source'ing are empty.

The contents of `Downloads/dx-toolkit/environment` are below:

```
# -*- Mode: shell-script -*-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# Copyright (C) 2013-2016 DNAnexus, Inc.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# This file is part of dx-toolkit (DNAnexus platform client libraries).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#   use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#   of the License at                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#   WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#   License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#   under the License.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# Source this file in a bash shell to initialize DNAnexus environment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# variables:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# $ source environment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

# This line is compatible with both bash and csh/tcsh. If running in csh, it sources the file "environment.csh" and quits.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

test ! -z "$version" && echo "$shell" | grep -q csh && set SOURCE=`echo $_ | cut -f 2 -d " "` && set SOURCE=`dirname "$SOURCE"` && source "$SOURCE/environment.csh" && exit

# Resolve the location of this file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ] ; do SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"; done

# Get RHEL version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
if [ -e /etc/redhat-release ] ; then
  RHEL_MAJOR_VERSION=$(grep -o "Red Hat Enterprise Linux .* release [0-9]\+" /etc/redhat-release | sed -e "s/Red Hat Enterprise Linux .* release //")
fi

export DNANEXUS_HOME="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

# Detect system installation of dx-toolkit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
if [ "$DNANEXUS_HOME" == "/etc/profile.d" ]; then

  export DNANEXUS_HOME="/usr/share/dnanexus"
  # Private Python packages. We really ought not pollute PYTHONPATH with these though.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  export PYTHONPATH="/usr/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
  export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/dnanexus-api-0.1.0.jar:${CLASSPATH}"

else

  export PATH="${DNANEXUS_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
  export CLASSPATH="${DNANEXUS_HOME}/lib/java/*:${CLASSPATH}"

  if [ "$RHEL_MAJOR_VERSION" == "7" ]; then
    export PYTHONPATH="${DNANEXUS_HOME}/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages:${DNANEXUS_HOME}/lib64/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
  else
    export PYTHONPATH="${DNANEXUS_HOME}/share/dnanexus/lib/python2.7/site-packages:${DNANEXUS_HOME}/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"
  fi

fi

# Note: The default I/O stream encoding in Python 2.7 (as configured on ubuntu) is ascii, not UTF-8 or the system locale                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# encoding. We reset it here to avoid having to set it for every I/O operation explicitly.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

eval "$(register-python-argcomplete dx|sed 's/-o default//')"

# Clean up old session files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(shopt -s nullglob;
 if [[ $HOME != "" ]]; then
     for session_dir in "${HOME}/.dnanexus_config/sessions/"*; do
         if ! ps -p $(basename "$session_dir") &> /dev/null; then
             rm -rf "$session_dir"
         fi
     done
 fi
)

if [[ -z "$DX_SECURITY_CONTEXT" && -n "$DX_AUTH_TOKEN" ]]; then
    export DX_SECURITY_CONTEXT="{\"auth_token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"auth_token\":\"$DX_AUTH_TOKEN\"}"
fi
```

I have a similar Ubuntu 14.04 VM working, would it be possible to rsync certain folders to it so that the non-working Ubuntu 14.04 is back to normal?

I seem to be stuck at this point, not knowing how to proceed any further.

Comment: You would need to know what the PYTHONPATH variable was before the change.

Comment: I don't know how to revert to the list of folders before, but I presume it was a combination of /usr/lib/python2.7 and /usr/local/lib/python2.7. Where can I find examples? What do I do when I know?

Comment: export PYTHON='/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7'

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal, is it PYTHON or PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Sorry PYTHONPATH

Comment: I tried what you suggested, still same issue. One of the programs I use complaints about a urllib3 library: `network_exceptions = (requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69506/discussion-between-719016-and-raman-sailopal).

Comment: Normally you don't need a PYTHONPATH (I don't have one). Looks more like you have broken the `requests` package. Have you got a directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages`? Otherwise what are the contents of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/`. You may just need to reinstall `requests`. Btw, on Ubuntu, you can install most popular python packages with `apt-get install python-{package}`

Comment: For next time, you can run a specific command with some environment variables without exporting them, like `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ python setup.py install`

Comment: I made some edits, re. @PatrickMevzek suggestion. I seem to be stuck at this point, not knowing how to proceed any further.

Comment: 1. What's the content of setup.py ? 2. What package you're trying to install (and success or not) ? 3. Which tutorial link you're referring to teach you `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ && sudo python setup.py install` ? 4. What error did you get at the first place (and how you get) which make you think you should restore PYTHONPATH ? 5. What happen if you play around in python interactive mode ?

Comment: updated the question now to describe the package I tried to install, successfully, and the one I am trying to run, currently unsuccessfully. Virtualenv also doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I am not sure what more information I can supply here. Waiting eagerly to be able to set up a bounty...

Comment: At this point I am tempted to make a backup of the data I have in the system and reinstall from afresh.

Comment: I don't understand why you run `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*/` to install(I don't see comment here mentioned it), `apt-get install python-requests` is inside `/usr/lib`, not `/usr/local/lib`. 
And I believe simply `sudo apt-get install python-requests` should get the job done. What's the output of `apt-cache show python-requests | grep Filename` ?

Comment: `apt-cache show python-requests | grep Filename
Filename: pool/main/r/requests/python-requests_2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3_all.deb
Filename: pool/main/r/requests/python-requests_2.2.1-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb
Filename: pool/main/r/requests/python-requests_2.2.1-1_all.deb`

Comment: Do you happen to have python3 as well? I have python2 and python3 side by side, and part of the directory structure I think is implied by your outputs seem to suggest that you have that, and that you may be mixing them somehow. If you do not have it, installing it may be a workaround for your needs, even if not a solution that gives you right now a working python2.

Comment: try at the command prompt `unset PYTHONPATH`, then `python`, and within python `import sys`, `sys.path`. Also try the same, with `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: added requested info @sancho.s

Comment: It is good if you add several pieces of info: 1) `echo $PYTHONPATH` (prior to any `source`ing), 2) contents of `Downloads/dx-toolkit/environment`

Comment: Replied to 1) and 2) now @sancho.s

Comment: I have a similar Ubuntu 14.04 VM working, would it be possible to rsync certain folders to it so that the non-working Ubuntu 14.04 is back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

The `develop` mode of setup.py will link your local code path to `PYTHONPATH`.

If you install the local package by 
`python setup.py develop`
, which will alter the system `PYTHONPATH` and drive you crazy to delete it from environment variables.

I find a correct way to uninstall them and restore your default `PYTHONPATH` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606457/removing-python-module-installed-in-develop-mode).
You need use the `--uninstall` or `-u` option to develop, i.e:

```
python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

PS: if you cannot uninstall the package at the first time, please try to reinstall and do uninstall again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the only solution is to reinstall the OS from scratch.

Comment: that's brutal :(

Comment: Next time exterminate all the python packages, exterminate also the python packages in your home and you will win.

Comment: What do you mean exterminate?